# @Html.Action link doesn't generate ActionMethod at the end of the string

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
@Html.ActionLink(MultiLanguageProvider.Instance.SelectAppropriate("Портфолио", "Portfolio"), "Index", "Portfolio")
```

The output must be something like ".../Portfolio/Index" but I get only ".../Portfolio" instead. The Index() method is there and if I force manually the correct adress ("Porfolio/Index") - it works perfectly. The problem is @Html.ActionLink output. What's wrong with that?

Comment: I've found the answer. I created custom folder "Portfolio". And at the same time there was "PortfolioController". Sort of misunderstandig of the processing logic, I believe. After I renamed "PortfolioFolder" - everything fine.

Comment: Please do add the answer in the question (I have removed your edit). Add you own answer and accept it to close this out (or delete the question).

Answer (score 0):

Use `Url.Action("action"...)` instead of `Html.Action(...)`